# iOS Spotify - album deeplink opens empty list

Tags: ios, spotify

I have such link that opens album on Spotify:
https://open.spotify.com/album/1woCvthHJakakroP6dXNxs

The problem I have is that when I open this link on the iOS, I'm redirected to the Spotify app to the empty album. I can see album's cover but it has no songs in it. 
Is there something I'm missing or is it Spotify's bug?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be Spotify bug. Works now.